implementing sso redirect and protect route using nextjs14 middleware
i am quite a bit struggling to find a solution of problem i am facing currently with nextjs 14 and middleware, So i have one route /some_route?token=afpojdsaipr433839 which i have provided to the client and they will hit this route with the token, now in my nextjs application i want to fetch this token from the param and make an api call to get the user details based on this token and store the data in my redux store and i also want to protect routes using middleware.
1 . can i make this above api call in middleware if yes how will i store data in redux as middleware runs on server and i cant access redux there

if i make a sso page client rendered and somehow manage to pass data in redux store, how will i get these data(redux data) in middleware if i am hitting another protected route.

if i am setting cookies to store the token or suppose a check that user hitted the protected route and store the data, there will be two source of truth, one in redux and one in cookie.


need clarification on above points if anyone has one or implemented this kind of feature before.
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
      let cookie = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;
    
      if (!cookie) {
        const headers = new Headers(request.headers);
        headers.set("Set-Cookie", "token=1234567; HttpOnly; Secure");
        console.log(request.nextUrl.search, "search");
        const redirectUrl = `/sso/${request.nextUrl.search}&nextRedirect=${request.nextUrl.pathname.split("/")[1]}`;
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(redirectUrl, request.url), {
          headers,
        });
      }
    }

